# Unable to set up hot module reload HMR for Symfony Webpack

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I am currently using manual reloads with `npx webpack` which are time consuming.
So, attempting to implement HMR using Webpack docs and [this tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/javascript-webpack/hot-module-replacement)

It does not throw any errors when I run `npm start`, tells me that files were generated but the files are not available in the destination directory `/dist`. If they are placed somewhere else, I could not find.

Also, the HMR as such seems to be working in the sense that it automatically recompiles once changes are made to the app files.

It automatically opens `localhost:8080` as well, but shows only the directory list or a message like `CANNOT GET`.

By the way, I do not use Symfony Encore.

The directory looks like this:

`- bin
- client // where the React files are
- config // Symfony
- node_modules
- public
  - dist // here goes Webpack's output ( normally )
  - index.php
- src // Symfony app files
- templates - Twig
- var 
- vendor
webpack.config.js`

The above webpack.config.js looks like below, in the latest config attempt

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { InjectManifest } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractCssChunks = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin');
 const HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
 const path = require('path');
 const useDevServer = true;
 const publicPath = useDevServer ? 'http://localhost:8080/public/dist/' : '/dist/';

 console.log('path', path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'));
 console.log('public path', publicPath);

module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
entry: './client/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath,
},
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
module: {
  ....
},
devServer: {
    // contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    allowedHosts: [
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
        'http://127.0.0.1:8001',
        'http://localhost:8000',
        'http://localhost:8001',
    ],
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
 ...
```